# how to avoid re-entrancy vulnerability warning?

Tags: solidity, wallet-transfer

Transfer amount to any address always showing the re-entrancy vulnerability warning. How to avoid this warning?

```
function completeChallenge(address _challengerAddress,address _challengeAddress,uint _index) internal returns(bool) {
   _challengerAddress.transfer(safeMul(challengeList[_challengerAddress][_challengeAddress][_index].challengeChargeAmountWei,2));
   return true;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't avoid warnings, listen to warnings, find the problem and fix it. Smart contracts handle money as you know.

Answer (score 1):

You should to update state before calling the transfer method. Because if you don’t update state then if the receiver is a smart contract it can call back your contract method to transfer again and again until your contract balance become zero

Comment: share any realtime example

Comment: You can search the very wellknown DAO fork to undertsnad more about the re entry vulnerability

Answer (score 0):

Unable to reproduce the warning in Solidity. 
What version are you using?
`pragma solidity ^0.4.17;` is the latest.

You may want to try assigning the `transferAmount` separately. This will at least **remove SafeMath's `safeMul`** code from the `.transfer` method call.

```
function completeChallenge(address _challengerAddress,address _challengeAddress,uint _index) internal returns(bool) {
    uint transferAmount = safeMul(challengeList[_challengerAddress][_challengeAddress][_index].challengeChargeAmountWei, 2);
   _challengerAddress.transfer(transferAmount);
   return true;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: latest one ^0.4.17 and after above change still showing the same warning.
You will see this warning in analysis section in remix compiler.